# Android app bundles: difference between asset files delivered as install-time Asset packs and traditional asset files

Tags: android, bundle, assets

In android apps as far as I know we can put custom files in the following asset folder: "**app\src\main\assets**".

New android App Bundle format (aab) allows to create asset files as asset packs with deliveryType = "install-time" and put them in the directories like "**asset-pack-name/src/main/assets**"

Asset files created using the first so-called traditional method and asset files created using the second asset pack method (with deliveryType = "install-time") are delivered when the app is installed. So what is the difference between these two methods? Which is preferable? I hope someone will help me to sort out this asset mess in my head.